Usage of なんなんだよ?


So in the previous page the character got told "I like you" and his answer is "I always thought you hated me"
Then in the next page he he adds
俺ってなんなんだよ
What exactly is なんなんだよ here? Obviously he's not asking the other person "what am I?".

そのあとのコマで、何かセリフあります？

It's basically just "What am I". But I don't know if he's saying "What kind of person am I" to himself or saying "What do I mean to you" to the other person.

@chocolate the other character say they regretted how  they acted


俺ってなんなんだよ
What exactly is なんなんだよ here? Obviously he's not asking the other person "what am I?".

I understand your question as partly related to parsing (how the phrase is constructed), and partly related to semantics (meaning).
The parsing

俺ってなんなんだよ
↓ [uncontracted]
俺【おれ】とて何【なん】なのだよ

The って is the contraction of とて, a kind of quotative.
The first なん is 何 in the contracted combining form.
The second なん is the contraction of なの, from attributive な + explanatory の.
The semantics

俺ってなんなんだよ

As @naruto notes in their comment on the question post itself, this is literally "What am I?" with possible overtones of "What the heck am I?"
Whether this is the character talking to themselves, or the character talking to another person with a sense of "What am I, to you?", is unclear from the limited context available.
